# rte flow for arp packet with dpdk

Tags: dpdk

Is there a way using rte_flow to send arp and ndp packet to specific rx queue with dpdk

In the rte_flow_item_type I don’t see an entry  for arp or ndp

For ipv4 I did the following way

```
                                                pattern[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;
                                                pattern[0].spec = NULL;

                                                pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4;
                                                pattern[1].spec = NULL;
```

What do i ned to do for arp and ndp? There is no RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ARP

- Dpdk version: 19.11
- NIC: mlx5, 100G mellanox card,

Comment: can you please update 1) DPDk version 2) NIC 3) firmware and 4) OS used. As mentioned in earlier RSS ticket support for HW offloads varies between dpdk version, firmware and NIC vendor.

Comment: based on the comment shared in the answer updated dpdk version and nic details to the question. Humbly requesting to share the details in the question in next attempt for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `v18.05-rc1`, there has been item type `RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ARP_ETH_IPV4`. That being said, it might be unsupported by the PMD in question.

Consider matching on the EtherType field instead:

```
#include <rte_byteorder.h>
#include <rte_ether.h>
#include <rte_flow.h>
```

```
        struct rte_flow_item_eth  item_eth_mask = {};
        struct rte_flow_item_eth  item_eth_spec = {};

        item_eth_spec.hdr.ether_type = RTE_BE16(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_ARP);
        item_eth_mask.hdr.ether_type = RTE_BE16(0xFFFF);

        pattern[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;
        pattern[0].mask = &item_eth_mask;
        pattern[0].spec = &item_eth_spec;
```

In what comes to NDP, perhaps it pays to check out `RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ICMP6_ND_*`. Again, these might be unsupported by the PMD in question. If that is the case, consider the use of `RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ICMP6` to redirect all of ICMPv6 to the dedicated queue.

Comment: Thansk for the help. I use dpdk 19.11 and mlx5 with a 100G mellanox card, RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ARP_ETH_IPV4 wasn't supported and the second one i don't see even. The rule looking in the bytes worked.
And in my version it is not hdr.ether_type but just type

Answer (score 0):

The default queue (with RSS disabled) for no match packet for all vendor PMD are queue 0. Expect for TAP PMD where multiple RX queue is supported by OS.

Since you have mentioned the DPDK version is 19.11, the best option is to make use rte_flow_item_eth to filter desired ether type. That is in DPDK 19.11

```
struct rte_flow_item_eth {
        struct rte_ether_addr dst; /**< Destination MAC. */
        struct rte_ether_addr src; /**< Source MAC. */
        rte_be16_t type; /**< EtherType or TPID. */
};
```

so using the following code snippet you can achieve packet type steering to desired queue

```
        struct rte_flow_attr attr = { .ingress = 1 };
        struct rte_flow_item pattern[10];
        struct rte_flow_action actions[10];
        struct rte_flow_action_queue actionqueue = { .index = 1 };
        struct rte_flow_item_eth eth;
        struct rte_flow_item_vlan vlan;
        struct rte_flow_item_ipv4 ipv4;
        struct rte_flow *flow;
        struct rte_flow_error error;

        struct rte_flow_item_eth  item_eth_mask;
        struct rte_flow_item_eth  item_eth_spec;

        /* memset item_eth_mask and item_eth_spec to 0  */

        item_eth_spec.hdr.ether_type = RTE_BE16(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_ARP);
        item_eth_mask.hdr.ether_type = 0xFFFF;

        /* setting the eth to pass all packets */
        pattern[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;
        pattern[0].spec = &eth;
        pattern[0].last = &item_eth_mask;
        pattern[0].mask = &item_eth_spec;

        /* end the pattern array */
        pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END;

        actions[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE;
        actions[0].conf = &actionqueue;
        actions[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END;

        /* validate and create the flow rule */
        if (!rte_flow_validate(port, &attr, pattern, actions, &error))
                flow = rte_flow_create(port, &attr, pattern, actions, &error);
        else
                printf("rte_flow err %s\n", error.message);
```

note: this fails on Intel X710 and E810 NIC as it support VLAn+IP+UDP|TCP|SCTP+Inner.

Comment: You wrote in the note that it fails on these nics?
Did you try to says that X710 and E810 support only these layers (VLAn+IP+UDP|TCP|SCTP+Inner)?

Comment: @yaron as per my testing with E810 I am only successfully to set RTE_FLOW with IP address passed. your current usecase is for non IP packets (ARP|NDP). Hence yes I believe it fails with DPDK 21.11.

Comment: @yaron quick question you are using Mellanox MLX5 or are you using Intel X710|E810 NIC? Just curious hence my next question `with RSS disabled the default queue is 0, so for all ARP|ND can easily processed by therad with queue 0 right? while other traffic are pinned to queue 1,2,3..n`

Comment: I now use mellanox mlx5 but i wan to be able to use for all the cards

Comment: ok, then the above solution is not going to work. Also please note sometime not all rules get applied to VF too.

Comment: I just tried with a vf and it didn't read any traffic - i don't know if it was because the rte_flow

Comment: @yaron better start debugging with trusted vf and right mac address